# Accessing the first returned object in python

Tags: python

I have a function `F()` that returns two objects. E.g. `ob1, ob2 = F()`.

Is there a way to just access ob1 and ignoring ob2 in the same line? something like `ob1 = F()`.

Comment: The short answer is "No"

Comment: @vovaminiof: That short answer would be "wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the [naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python) for throwaway variables:

```
ob1, _ = F()
```

Another option is to get the first item from the result of `F()`:

```
obj1 = F()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions can never return two objects at once.  Instead, your function is returning a tuple that *contains* two objects.

This means that you can use indexing to get the object you want:

```
>>> def F():
...     return 1, 2
...
>>> ob1 = F()[0]
>>> ob1
1
>>>
```

Remember that it is the comma `,` that creates a tuple, not the parenthesis (if any):

```
>>> t = 1, 2
>>> t
(1, 2)
>>> t = (1, 2)
>>> t
(1, 2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the result will be a tuple, just access the position you need:

```
ob1 = F()[0]
```